# basic active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app with a three models called author, books and authorships. a book has many authors through a joint model called authorship and author has many books through a joint model called authorships for example

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :books, :through => :authorships
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :author_ids
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
end

class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id, :author_id
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end
```

Now my question is, How can i find books that as the similar authors any selected one

for instance, `<% book = Book.first %>`
something like

```
<% book.similar_authors.each do |book| %>
  #......
<% end %>
```

What kind of query will i use to define `similar_authors`

Comment: What makes an author similar to another one?

Comment: similar author in the sense?

Comment: The author_ids. Which means finding books with similar author_ids

Comment: displaying books with the same author_ids as the selected book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship seems to define it already. Try this:

```
<% book.authors.each do |author| %>
  <% author.books.each do |book| %>
    #......
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or, if you want to only have one iterator, and no dupes, maybe something like (this is the same as above):

```
<% book.authors.map { |author| author.books }.flatten.uniq.sort.each do |book|  %>
  #......
<% end %>
```

And, to come around full circle, maybe in your model (this is the same as above):

```
def books_from_similar_authors
  authors.map { |author| author.books }.flatten.uniq.sort
end
```

Comment: Will a book be displayed twice in this case. meaning if four authors have the same book will it be displayed four times.

Comment: Yes, updated to account for that (air code, may need to tweak slightly)

Comment: I'd caution against doing all the work in Rails since it will use a lot more resources. You're better off crafting a DB query (via a scope or method)

Comment: Updated to reflect that concern, which is valid. I think language understanding is more important than premature optimization. It sounds like this site is going to need some good caching, anyway, if it gets any legs...

Comment: will this be done in the book or authors model as i do not have `author_id:` in my book model

Comment: Whops, yeah, I totally spaced on the join model - I'm sorry.

Comment: running the query does not actually find the different books it just returns the same book in an array..

Comment: Yeah, that was a bad example, I'm sorry - it has been removed.

Comment: even the current example too.

Comment: It should find all of the books by every author of the current book... The data exists that would return multiple books, I assume?

Comment: try `authors.map { |author| author.books }.flatten.uniq.sort`

Comment: Sweet, kinda figured - I inadvertently overlooked it, earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way,

**for example**

suppose your `author name` is `"xyz"`,

in your model

```
def similar_authors(name)
  where("author_name = ?", name )
end
```

and in your controller

```
book.similar_authors('xyz') # you will get all books that have author_name is 'xyz'
```

if you want to optimize then you can also make a `scope` for that

Comment: This will work great for just one single author name. what of were the author name is an array like `%w("xyz abc ddd ccc eee")` how do i do this